# Buying fruits example in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

> Question: A grocery store sells apples, oranges, and grapefruits. Assume that each kind of fruit is identical and that the chosen order does not matter. Suppose that there are an unlimited of grapefruits but only 9 apples and 10 oranges in the
> store. In how many ways can 12 fruits be chosen.

My idea is to start from all the possible cases without restriction and subtract the cases that don't match the requirement. Suppose there're unlimited supplies for all fruits, then there will be $\binom{12+3-1}{3-1}$ ways to choose fruits (is that correct?). Then I'll subtract the cases with more than 9 apples or 10 oranges. For example:

10 apples: there're $\newcommand\mchoose[2]{\left(\!\!\left({#1}\atop{#2}\right)\!\!\right)}\mchoose 22$ ways (consider oranges and grapefruits)

11 apples or 11 oranges: $\mchoose 21$ ways

Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: The $3^{12}$ is wrong, as you said that order does not matter.  Try [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the correction, should that be $\binom{12+3-1}{3-1}$ instead? Should I use multiset for the cases I mentioned below?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  After that, just enumerate the "bad" cases, as you suggest.  Just go case by case.  Tedious, but not difficult.

Comment: @lulu Thank you

Comment: @lulu as there are only $12$ fruits, both apples and oranges cannot violate their limits at the same time. So we can alternatively extend the same stars and bars method easily for counting bad cases too.

Comment: @MathLover  Perfectly true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track except that the all fruits of the same kind are identical. $3^{12}$ would be right if all fruits were different.

So you should instead be using stars and bars. You are looking for solution to

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 12$

where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are number of apples, oranges and grapefruits.

That is given by, $\displaystyle {12 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1} = {14 \choose 2}$

Now subtract all unfavorable cases from it as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! For the unfavorable cases I should use multiset, is that because we're choosing more than one categories?

Comment: You can simply solve the same equation I solved above. $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 12$. Now if $x_1 \geq 10$, you are solving $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 12 - 10 = 2$ which is ${4 \choose 2} = 6$. Now when $x_2 \geq 11$, find the same.

Comment: For $x_2 = 11, 12$, it is anyway easy to see there are $3$ possibilities. So total unfavorable cases are $9$.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps

Comment: @IGY you are welcome.